# How to get the same user UID for the new phone number Firestore Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using `user's uid` to query information from the `firestore` database. The problem is when I allow user to change their phone number, the new number is stored into the authentication database and also generates new `user's uid`. This makes the app crash since the app uses the last user uid.

**NB:** The `user uid` creates a collection which is very impossible to change the collection's name.

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you sure you are not creating a new user by chance ?

Comment: "also generates new user's uid" That should not be happening if you call `updatePhoneNumber`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential). Can you show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj and @Frank Van Puffelen for your questions which lead to a fixed answer. I was updating the `phone number` simultaneously calling the `sign with phone number` function. PROBLEM SOLVED.